# Enabling Proguard in app module effects other module, and crashing application

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

If I set `minifyEnabled true`, the app starts crashing on opening an activity that is using a third party library.

> art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI
>   NewGlobalRef called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   no "I" field "mALFactoryContext" in class
>   "Lcom/ntreaming/nplayerengine/NFactory;" or its superclasses

The library has been added as a separate module in my application. It has its different `gradle` and `proguard` files. I have not enabled `proguard` from library `gradle` file.

The library is also using `.so` files.

If i set `minifyEnabled false`, it starts working successfully.

Kindly guide me how to tell proguard to not effect other modules.

Comment: add -dontwarn line for that module in proguard rules

Comment: donotwarn libraryName? but its not giving me any warning

Comment: -dontwarn yourmodule         like this line should be in proguardrule pro

Comment: @NarenderReddy the crash is still there

Answer (score 0):

in your app level proguard file try this

```
-keep class android.app.**
```